# Get if page visit is organic, PPC or from website

Tags: php, analytics, http-referer

I am working on a website, where I have a page like

```
http://www.test.com/contact-us
```

I need to track from where a user is visiting this page. For example:

```
- From a Search engine
- From web website
- From PPC ads
- From Feeds
etc
```

And need to save it into DB.
Is there a way I can achieve this in php.

--

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` for that purpose.
But its an optional key in $_SERVER variable .You will get `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` only when someone will visit your site from any other source.

Possible Sources are -

- Another site
- Another page from your site

You will not get any **HTTP_REFERER** key if user is directly visiting your site by entering your web address in browser.

Comment: There are many search engines, ad agencies, how will I track if source is search engine or ads, even if we track the HTTP_REFERER

Comment: HTTP_REFERER will contain the last address from where you are visiting . If it will be related to google then google is definitely the referer for you .Same will happen in case with ad agencies also.